# Make outer div fit inner div text

Tags: html, css

I have an outer div that might have different sizes. Also, I have inner div with some text

Example:

```
<div style="height:100px; width:100px;background-color:red">

  <div>
      iughwekrug hiwerjgergwteg iuhtighrtj grtjng kjhnlgwjen lkgjnwe kljgnlkwerjn gkljewrn gkljnwerklgjnweklrjgnklwejrngkljewrngkljnwerkljgnklwerjngkljewrn klgjenwrklgjnwerklgjn klewrjgnklwejrnglkjwe wjbtlgwrljnvlwkj englkjwn tkljnwjglwtkjnglkjewrng lkjwerng lkjwetngl kjwgklj nwtgkljnglkjwtn glkjnrtkljgn wkjtgn lkwtjnglk wjnkgl nwtkljgnkltrjn lkjntlk jnlkgnkltjng kbb jrtnvjht fjgljnerkljng ljwernlgkjwnelkjgn lkwejrgnl kwjetng lkwjngkjwntglk jwntgkljnwkj nwlklkwjntglkjwn gkjwngkljwnt lkjgnwtkljng klwtngkljwtn lkjwtngklj nwtklgjnwklt jnglkwjnt gkljwntlkg jnwlktgn klwjngl jnwtklgjnwkl tjngklwjtng klwjntgkl jwtngklj nwtklgjnkw ljngkjwnt klgjnwtklj gnjrwbjwr
  </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g2an6yez/

The problem is background of outer div has a border on top of inner div text.

[image]

Are there any way to make a border at text line and not split letters?

Are there any way to know which size I have to put for a div to match text lines?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are asking - maybe this will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/g2an6yez/5/

Comment: @demonhunter24 I was asking about the case when inner div bigger than outer div and I have the overflow. In that case, I don't want to have letters cut at the half.

Comment: So change the line-height so you know how many lines fit... If it is dynamic, than set a size when the page is loaded and resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think line-height will help you.

```
line-height: 20px;
```

Especially 20px, because in your 100px Box you can place exactly 5 lines.

Comment: In that case height of my box should be multiple to 20px. Well, it is an option but it will be nice to have more flexible solution.

Comment: Can you give me another example, so I can fully understand what kind of flexibility you need? Maybe then I can help a little bit better... because I seem to not fully understand your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `height` for your red box that is a multiple of the text's `line-height`.

In the example below, I want the red box to be 4 lines tall, so I set `height` to 4 x 1.5 = 6em.

```css
.box {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 6em; /* this will be 4 lines */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="text">
    iughwekrug hiwerjgergwteg iuhtighrtj grtjng kjhnlgwjen lkgjnwe kljgnlkwerjn gkljewrn gkljnwerklgjnweklrjgnklwejrngkljewrngkljnwerkljgnklwerjngkljewrn klgjenwrklgjnwerklgjn klewrjgnklwejrnglkjwe wjbtlgwrljnvlwkj englkjwn tkljnwjglwtkjnglkjewrng lkjwerng
    lkjwetngl kjwgklj nwtgkljnglkjwtn glkjnrtkljgn wkjtgn lkwtjnglk wjnkgl nwtkljgnkltrjn lkjntlk jnlkgnkltjng kbb jrtnvjht fjgljnerkljng ljwernlgkjwnelkjgn lkwejrgnl kwjetng lkwjngkjwntglk jwntgkljnwkj nwlklkwjntglkjwn gkjwngkljwnt lkjgnwtkljng klwtngkljwtn
    lkjwtngklj nwtklgjnwklt jnglkwjnt gkljwntlkg jnwlktgn klwjngl jnwtklgjnwkl tjngklwjtng klwjntgkl jwtngklj nwtklgjnkw ljngkjwnt klgjnwtklj gnjrwbjwr
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: there is a `lh` [line-height length unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) in the [css4 draft spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#lh) which is said to be

> Equal to the computed value of the line-height property of the element on which it is used, converted to an absolute length.

but this is still marked as experimental and lacks any support.

Comment: That solution is good and actually answers my question but I might have different size of outer div and that means I have always control it what makes things a little bit complicated. It will be great to have more flexible solution.

Comment: @Neir0 I've updated to set the height with a relative unit as a multiple of lineheight.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question properly, if this is not what u meant by not allowing your letters from splitting but what u can try is setting a 
white-space:nowrap;
overflow-y:scroll;
to your outer div so that your text does not break nor will it overflow from the outer div or try using the below code snippet accordingly

```html
<div style="height:100px; width:300px;background-color:red;overflow:scroll;overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;">
  <div>
      iughwekrug hiwerjgergwteg iuhtighrtj grtjng kjhnlgwjen lkgjnwe kljgnlkwerjn gkljewrn gkljnwerklgjnweklrjgnklwejrngkljewrngkljnwerkljgnklwerjngkljewrn klgjenwrklgjnwerklgjn klewrjgnklwejrnglkjwe wjbtlgwrljnvlwkj englkjwn tkljnwjglwtkjnglkjewrng lkjwerng lkjwetngl kjwgklj nwtgkljnglkjwtn glkjnrtkljgn wkjtgn lkwtjnglk wjnkgl nwtkljgnkltrjn lkjntlk jnlkgnkltjng kbb jrtnvjht fjgljnerkljng ljwernlgkjwnelkjgn lkwejrgnl kwjetng lkwjngkjwntglk jwntgkljnwkj nwlklkwjntglkjwn gkjwngkljwnt lkjgnwtkljng klwtngkljwtn lkjwtngklj nwtklgjnwklt jnglkwjnt gkljwntlkg jnwlktgn klwjngl jnwtklgjnwkl tjngklwjtng klwjntgkl jwtngklj nwtklgjnkw ljngkjwnt klgjnwtklj gnjrwbjwr
  </div>

</div>
```

hope this helps :D